# Interpreting semidirect product in GAP in terms of underlying groups

Tags: finite-groups, gap

I obtained the group $G$ which is the semidirect product $(\mathbb{Z}_5 \times \mathbb{Z}_5) \rtimes \mathbb{Z}_3$ in GAP as below.

```
gap> m:=[[4,0],[0,2]]*One(GF(5));
[ [ Z(5)^2, 0*Z(5) ], [ 0*Z(5), Z(5) ] ]
gap> s1:=SemidirectProduct(Group(m),GF(5)^2);
<matrix group of size 100 with 3 generators>
```

And when I obtained the elements of $G$ I get a list which continues as follows.

```
gap> Elements(s1);
[ [ [ Z(5)^0, 0*Z(5), 0*Z(5) ], [ 0*Z(5), Z(5)^0, 0*Z(5) ], [ 0*Z(5), 0*Z(5), Z(5)^0 ] ],
  [ [ Z(5)^0, 0*Z(5), 0*Z(5) ], [ 0*Z(5), Z(5)^0, 0*Z(5) ], [ 0*Z(5), Z(5)^0, Z(5)^0 ] ],
  [ [ Z(5)^0, 0*Z(5), 0*Z(5) ], [ 0*Z(5), Z(5)^0, 0*Z(5) ], [ 0*Z(5), Z(5), Z(5)^0 ] ],
  [ [ Z(5)^0, 0*Z(5), 0*Z(5) ], [ 0*Z(5), Z(5)^0, 0*Z(5) ], [ 0*Z(5), Z(5)^2, Z(5)^0 ] ],...
```

I want to write the elements as $(\bar0,(\bar0,\bar0)),(\bar0,(\bar0,\bar1)),(\bar0,(\bar0,\bar2))$,....

Can someone please tell how to interpret the elements in the above list which are present as `[ Z(5)^0, 0*Z(5), 0*Z(5) ], [ 0*Z(5), Z(5)^0, 0*Z(5) ] ...` to obtain the form I want.

What does `Z(5)^0`, `0*Z(5)` mean?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Your matrix m has order 4, not 3! That's why it reports the order of the group at 100 instead of 75. The finite field notation is explained in the manual https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap59.html

Comment: You can get the element representation you want using the help of the Embedding and Representation commands described at https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap49_mj.html#X87FE512E7DB7346C

Answer (score 1):

The notation `Z(5)` stands for a generator of the unit group of the finite field with five elements. So `Z(5)^0` is $1$, and `0*Z(5)` is $0$ is the finite field. The command `IntFFE` will convert these numbers for you.

```
gap> IntFFE(Z(5));            
2 
gap> IntFFE(Z(5)^2);            
4
```